# Divergence by definition for the sequence $a_{n}=(-1)^n\frac{n}{n+5}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the sequence $a_{n}=(-1)^n\frac{n}{n+5}$

How can I show that it diverges by definition, that is:

$\exists\space\epsilon>0;\forall\space n_{0}\in\mathbb{N},\exists\space n\ge n_{0};|a_{n}-l|\ge\epsilon$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examine the difference between successive terms,
$$
\left | (-1)^m\frac{m}{m+1}+(-1)^{m+2}\frac{m+1}{m+7}\right|=
\left | \frac{m}{m+1}+\frac{m+1}{m+7}\right|
=\frac{m}{m+1}+\frac{m+1}{m+7}\\
\geq \frac{m}{m+1}\geq\frac{1}{2}
$$
whenever $m\geq 1$. Now, given $\epsilon=1/2$, can you see that for any $N\in \mathbb{N}$, we have for any $\ell\in \mathbb{R}$, either
$$
|a_{N+1}-\ell|\geq1/2
$$
or 
$$
|a_{N}-\ell|\geq1/2
$$